# Can't migrate migrated comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, migration, moderator-tools

[A question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209578/extreme-fps-drop-in-counter-strike-global-offensive) arrived at Arqade from SU, and it had a lot of comments. I tried to migrate them to chat, but it didn't work, throwing the error:

> Can't move comments from a user without an account

When a question is migrated, if a comment user doesn't have an account on the target site, the comment arrives with no author. This then means the comment can't be migrated to chat, as unlike comments, chat messages need an owner.

While fixing the authorship of the comment might be a bit much, assigning ownership of the authorless comment's migrated chat message to the Stack Exchange user (with a bracketed original-author) would prevent this from causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the benefit of moving those comments to chat over simply deleting them?

There's even an answer on that question now that summarizes the relevant points - not much point in moving them to chat.

In a more general case, this sort of thing sounds like a pretty narrow edge case - a migration with an active comment discussion that the OP follows to the other site (where they previously didn't have a profile).

Comment: Fair enough. I'm guessing this is a pretty rare situation!